# How to do if elif statements in postgressql and save the outcome in a new column?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

i'm quite new to postgressql, so i have a table called public.dim_products with a column called weight_kg
what i would like to do is given some weight in the weight ranges below to set up a new column called weight_class and have these values

```
`+--------------------------+-------------------+
 | weight_class VARCHAR(?)  | weight range(kg)  |
 +--------------------------+-------------------+
 | Light                    | < 2               |
 | Mid_Sized                | 3 - 40            |
 | Heavy                    | 41 - 140          |
 | Truck_Required           | > 141             |
 +----------------------------+-----------------+`
```

I've had a quick look at case statements and it seems to be what i'm after but when i do the statement it comes up with an error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError) syntax error at or near "CASE"

`SELECT weight_kg FROM public.dim_products
 CASE 
     WHEN weight_kg < 2 THEN Light
     WHEN weight_kg > 2 AND weight_kg < 41 THEN Mid_Sized
     WHEN weight_kg > 40 AND weight_kg <141 THEN HEAVY
     WHEN weight_kg > 140 THEN Truck_Required
 END weight_class;`
```

Ideally this shoul've created a column and had all these new mapping?

Using Kamran suggestion this is the corrected version of the syntax

```
dim_products_create_weight_class_col = """SELECT weight_kg,
 CASE 
     WHEN weight_kg::float < 2 THEN 'Light'
     WHEN weight_kg::float >= 2 AND weight_kg::float < 41 THEN 'Mid_Sized'
     WHEN weight_kg::float >= 41 AND weight_kg::float <141 THEN 'HEAVY'
     WHEN weight_kg::float >= 141 THEN 'Truck_Required'
 END AS weight_class
 FROM public.dim_products;
```

The issue is, it still didn't create the weight_class column?

Comment: Please edit your question and post the error message.

Comment: You are looking for [Range types](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rangetypes.html). So something like `select int4range(3, 41); [3,41)` and then `select int4range(3, 41) @> 5; t`.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer i've added the error message, its just a syntax error

Comment: @AdrianKlaver i'll have a look at range types now and come back to you

Comment: Why do you cast a column in your update query? There should be no need for that. And why to a float?

Comment: @FrankHeikens its just the steps that i need to follow, whereas the second part, is actually altering the column data types, its kind of backwards

Comment: @FrankHeikens the datatype was text originally when i cleaned the data source and upload the dataframe to postgressql

Comment: @FrankHeikens while i have you here, i'm using sqlalachemy to interact with the postgressql by sending the sql queries as multiline python string like i have it typed out in my code, should i be doing that or should i just use ORM that sqlalchemy inttroduces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of your CASE expression is incorrect. Here's a corrected version that follows the proper syntax:

```
SELECT weight_kg, 
       CASE 
           WHEN weight_kg < 2 THEN 'Light'
           WHEN weight_kg >= 2 AND weight_kg < 41 THEN 'Mid_Sized'
           WHEN weight_kg >= 41 AND weight_kg < 141 THEN 'HEAVY'
           WHEN weight_kg >= 141 THEN 'Truck_Required'
       END AS weight_class
FROM public.dim_products;
```

SELECT statement only retrieves the data. If you want to update an existing column, you may use following:

```
UPDATE public.dim_products
SET weight_class = 
       CASE 
           WHEN weight_kg < 2 THEN 'Light'
           WHEN weight_kg >= 2 AND weight_kg < 41 THEN 'Mid_Sized'
           WHEN weight_kg >= 41 AND weight_kg < 141 THEN 'HEAVY'
           WHEN weight_kg >= 141 THEN 'Truck_Required'
       END;
```

If `weight_class` column doesn't exist, you can create with:

```
ALTER TABLE public.dim_products
ADD COLUMN weight_class varchar(20);
```

Comment: I was just doing this now so i ended up doing exactly like you had, (put my from at the end of the statement and added AS next to END) but then i  ran into another error saying column light doesn't exist, which i'm guessing is due to not putting it in quotations

Comment: Yes, also check your if conditions, you are skipping 2 value, if that is intended, you may need to add ELSE condition.

Comment: i've just tried this but the issue was that i didn't create the new column weight_class, it seems to run the sql query fine now but the new column wasn't created

Comment: ohhh now that was just a dumb error on my part with the conditional

Comment: Thank you so much i learnt so much from your answer

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that we start from the beginning:

**1. First of all - we are creating blank table**

`CREATE TABLE weight_ranges_classes ( weight_class VARCHAR(30) , weight_range int4range,);`

(sorry for formatting)

**2. Below is a solution closely related to your scope**

**a) Create table with ranges**

```
INSERT INTO weight_ranges_classes VALUES
('Light', '[, 2)'), 
('Mid_Sized', '[2, 40]'), 
('Heavy', '[41, 140]'), 
('Truck_Required', '[141,]') ;
```

**b) After that you can use ranges to select proper value**

```
select 
weight_class,
weight_range,
from 
weight_ranges_classes 
where 
--\/ here you defining desired ranges of outcome query
'[2,5]'::intrange @>weight_range
```

More information about ranges in postgres you cen found out here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2R9Vqd4x6o

Comment: Thank, thats a different way of doing it, the previous answer that i accepted helped me a lot but i will have a look at ranges since it does look like a more concise way of doing things

Comment: also quick question i'm doing this all in python but since i'm using multilined strings to send the query to the sqlalchemy engine, I was wondering if this might cause a issue or if a hiring manager saw it would they be thinking 'yeah this is just waiting for a sql injection'

Comment: I dont see your specific example, but IMO if you have chance to use parameters to protect code against that attack, lets do that.

Comment: To capture the limit in the original question `[0, 2]` should be `[0, 2)` and `[3, 40]` should be `[2, 40]`.  I would suggest rewriting all the values to maintain a consistent upper bound inclusive or exclusive.  FYI, `[0, 2)` can be restated as `[, 2)` and  `[141, 2000]` as  `[141,]` to mean `val < 2` or `val > 141`.